# Issue with code designed to close browser when hitting refresh button on the same browser

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that is called via a batch file from a shared drive so that a couple of users can run it centrally. I added a code I saw here in one of the posts:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })
```

to ensure that the CMD prompt window closes when the browser window or tab is closed. That works perfectly.

The problem comes down to the browser refresh button. When pressed, it closes the CMD prompt window and leaves the shiny window in disconnected mode.

I want to be able to click refresh (if possible at all) without essentially shutting down the app.

Thannks

-Luis

Comment: Just to add: I don't know JavaScript, but I'm afraid it will be needed for this if possible at all, since in Shiny it works like that - I mean, when the refresh button is pressed, previous session is closed and the new session is started. Maybe some button in the app to use `stopApp()`? Or key event, like esc? [keys package](https://github.com/r4fun/keys). But then tab in browser will stay in "disconnect" mode and I don't know if this is possible to close the tab using JS.